# Taking user input and using it to identify appropriate ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have this for my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from account.forms import RegistrationForm, AccountAuthenticationForm, AccountUpdateForm
from framework.models import Company

# Create your views here.

def registration(request):
  context = {}
  
  user = request.user
  if user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect("index")
  if request.POST:
    updated_request = request.POST.copy()
    for entity in Company.objects.all():
      if entity in Company.objects.all():
        updated_request['company'] = Company.objects.get_or_create(entity)[0]
          form = RegistrationForm(updated_request)

    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
      email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
      first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
      last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
      raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
      address1 = form.cleaned_data.get('address1')
      address2 = form.cleaned_data.get('address2')
      city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
      state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
      zipcode = form.cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
      account = authenticate(username=username,password=raw_password)
      return redirect('index')
    else:
      context['registration_form'] = form
  else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
    context['registration_form'] = form
  return render(request, 'account/register.html' , context)
```

I'm trying to take the user's input in the form of text and compare it against the database to select a Company that they are working for, I will also add an else statement that will create a new one if one that is exact doesn't already exist.

I know that this means that user's can just continually create new companies, but this will not be a problem because all accounts will be manually reviewed before being activated, so if someone makes a typo or has slight deviation between the exact naming we are using for their company it will be caught before any errors can be made.

as for my models this is the code for them:

**account/models.py**

```
from framework.models import Company
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# ...

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=64, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="US")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,related_name="employees",null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','company', 'first_name','last_name', 'address1', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode']

    objects = MyAccountManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**framework/models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So I need help getting it to where a user can type in a name of their company and it will search the list of existing companies and either set their company equal to an existing one or creating a new one.

The main error code I am receiving is: Cannot assign `"'Company object (1)'": "Account.company" must be a "Company" instance.`

If you need any other info please send a message my way.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop over all your records here.

```
for entity in Company.objects.all():
```

`Django` has inbuilt methods to return filters and searches etc, no need to loop over `all()` here.

---

You can use `get_or_create()` to specify the fields you that are required when passing to `get_or_create()` such as below, if only `name` is required.

```
obj, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=company)
```

Now `obj` will always contain the created or fetched row from your database. Then just set `updated_request['company']`

```
updated_request['company'] = obj.pk
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and  I received this error "cannot unpack non-iterable Company object"